# Present perfect vs past simple?

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

Friend : Let's go
Me : My brother **has taken** my car, we have to wait until he come back.
Or
My brother **took** my car, we have to wait until he come back

Comment: I think you've lots of questions about perfect tense. So I recommend you read our [Cannonical post #2 What is perfect and when should I use it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it).

Comment: My brother has taken my car, we have to wait until he comes back!

Comment: @user178049's link is a good one: check out Section 4, the second item.

Comment: And in case it hadn't been clear from SovereignSun's corrections, you need to say, "comes" no matter which tense you ultimately decide on.

Comment: Both are fine. It depends on what the speaker wants to say. There is a difference between both are fine and deciding which to use and a mistaken use of one or the other. There are times when PP is a mistake: /He has taken my car yesterday/ being an example of one of the most common ones.